# Why is compiler changing if condition to a ternary operator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have this following sample code

```
public static void Method()
{
    AutoResetEvent autoReset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    bool canceled = false;

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        canceled = true;
        autoReset.Set();
    }).Start();

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something");
    } while (autoReset.WaitOne() && !canceled);

    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}
```

And I'm trying to achived 100% code coverage. So I just made a simple Test (that test nothing, but that is not the point), ran it and analysed the code coverage :

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Program.Method();
}
```

The code coverage gave me that only a portion of the `while` line was executed :

[image: Code coverage]

After some research, I tried to decompile the code and found out that the compiler was changing my `do while` to :

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing something");
    flag = (!autoResetEvent.WaitOne() ? false : !flag1);
}
while (flag);
```

So the `false` in the conditional operator is never tested (and is impossible to test [because `WaitOne` never returns `false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx). A simple solution is just to move out the `WaitOne` of the `while` condition and inside the `do`. So my questions are :

1. Why is the compiler changing the and condition to a conditional operator?
2. Is there a way to prevent the compiler doing this by keeping the condition like it is in the while and without affecting how the rest of the code is compiled? In reality, the condition in the while is more complex than this. It would be simpler and more readable to just keep it like this.

Comment: Why do you think it's a result of the compiler and not of the decompiler?

Comment: Good question. I assumed it was the result of the compiler because it was coherent to why I wasn't getting covered to 100%. Is posting the IL prove it is the result of the compiler?

Comment: Code coverage is a really dangerous metric. 100% coverage tells you nothing about the quality of your code or test cases -- you can still miss critical test cases and bugs even with 100% code coverage. Don't shoot for 100% coverage just to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&&` operator in C# *is* a conditional operator, or more commonly known as a **short-circuiting operator**. The right-hand-side operand is only evaluated if the left-hand-side evaluates to `true`. This means even if you don't see it in the source code, a branch exists in the compiled code to bypass the evaluation of the right-hand-side any time the left-hand-side is `false`.

This can impact code coverage in many ways. If you are measuring by [branch coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage#Basic_coverage_criteria), then the only way to achieve 100% coverage would be to create a test where `autoResetEvent.WaitOne()` returns `false` (e.g. by [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)). However, if you are measuring coverage by other metrics (e.g. statement coverage), you might not need to do anything at all to achieve 100% coverage.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, shot-circuiting only exists in C# and doesn't exists in IL?

Comment: There is no `&&` opcode in CIL, so the compiler converts it to the equivalent behavior using branching instructions.